# Gaining access to jndi environment variables within a Tomcat LifecycleListener

Tags: tomcat

I'm using a LifecycleListener in tomcat to initialize some objects required by contexts in my web server.  Within LifecycleListener I would like to have access to GlobalNamingResources Environment variables to keep the configuration for the server inside the server.xml file.  When trying various approaches I get the following error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name java:comp is not bound in this Context
```

I'm assuming that the jndi is not initialized by this stage of the server startup process.  Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

JNDI is set up in a LifecycleListener also but NamingContextListener is the last one. I don't think you can change that.

The solution is to initialize application in a ServletContextListener. This is always initialized after all LifecycleListeners are started.

You can import all the global JNDI context to the webapp using `<ResourceLink>`.